# How can I get maya to treat an action I perform with open maya as undoable?

Tags: python, maya, undo

I'm looking for a way to undo an action performed by an open Maya function.  I was asked to make a tool for Maya to scale multiple selected UV shells relative to their own pivots.  This went well, but my code does not result in something that can be undone with the undo short-cut.

The function I'm looking to undo is:

`MFnMesh.setSomeUVs(uvIds, uValues, vValues, uvSet='')`

After pulling the old UV values I apply the scale and then use this function to push the new co-ordinates back onto the UVs.  I'm looking for some way to put my changes with this function onto the undo queue so that the user can undo a mistake.  I'm trying to avoid using cmds to do the scaling as that will mess with the UV selection.

This is my first time programming in Maya so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just cache the selection into a variable or a set and restore it, the do the work in cmds. Script operations are undoable by default.

Alternately, you can implement your function as an [MpxCommand](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2015/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_class_m_px_command_html). If you implement the `doIt`, `undoIt` and `redoIt` methods you'll be in the regular undo queue. However it is up to you to implement them; you'll have to store the necessary data to do and undo the work inside your MpxCommand instance.

Comment: If I'm understanding how to use MpxCommand maya keeps track the classes state at each an event I want to be undone.   I will have implement what to do when it is undone using the information that will be stored in that saved state.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the storage of the save and restore data is internal to the instance of the mpxcommand: the instance is the thing that actually goes into the undo stack.  Maya will store the object for you and call its doIt and UndoIt methods but you're responsible for keeping enough data to peform undos and redos